# Failed to load plugin 'import' declared in 'package.json » eslint-config-react-app': Cannot find module 'typescript/package.json'

Tags: reactjs, eslint

```
ERROR in [eslint] Failed to load plugin 'import' declared in 'package.json » eslint-config-react-app': Cannot find module 'typescript/package.json'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\USER\Desktop\bitcamp-homework_1\homework1\node_modules\eslint-plugin-import\lib\rules\no-duplicates.js
- C:\Users\USER\Desktop\bitcamp-homework_1\homework1\node_modules\eslint-plugin-import\lib\index.js
- C:\Users\USER\Desktop\bitcamp-homework_1\homework1\node_modules\@eslint\eslintrc\dist\eslintrc.cjs
```

I tried to create new react app with "npx create-react-app", after running npm start, this error appeared. I dont even using ts. what can I do?

I try reinstall but wont work.
Sometimes it runs without error.

*[UPDATE] as i found out that was directory problem. (file in file)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add :

```
{
"eslint.workingDirectories": ["./front", "./back", "./shared"]
}
```

to `settings.json`

Comment: may that work. Thanks, but why I need to create manually this file? And my error happens cuz of directory?